# Can't run scripts anymore due to Error 401: deleted_client The OAuth client was deleted

Tags: google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform

I linked my google apps script project to a project on GCP. Then I deleted the GCP because I didn't need it. Now, I can't run scripts inside my google apps script project.

[image]

First, I got this popup. Then, after clicking the first button I get to error message in my subject line.

Originally, I linked from google apps script to GCP from the Resources/Google Cloud Project option. There is no option to unlink...

How can unlink my Google Apps Script from my now-deleted GCP.

Comment: Try copying all of the scripts to another spreadsheet.

Comment: Yes - that is what I ended up doing. I basically started from scratch and copied all the content from my scripts.

Comment: You can actually do that with Apps Script API but it would probably take a while to figure out how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

As written in the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/cloud-platform-projects#switching_to_a_different_standard_gcp_project),

> You can't switch a script project to use a default GCP project. Default GCP projects are deleted once the script project they were created for is set to use a standard GCP project.

You cannot unlink as the default project is deleted. You have to create a new GCP project and link to the new project, which will automatically unlink from it's old project.

Comment: Would there have been a way to unlink the default project before it was deleted? I couldn't find a way...

Comment: @MatthewSchwarz Just link it to a new one. It'll automatically be unlinked from the old one.